# I cant install Video thumbnail in my laravel project

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg on my laravel project but I am getting this errors.

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove evenement/evenement v2.1.0
- Conclusion: don't install evenement/evenement v2.1.0
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.5.0 requires evenement/evenement ~1.0 -> satisfiable by evenement/evenement[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.5.1 requires evenement/evenement ~1.0 -> satisfiable by evenement/evenement[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.6.0 requires evenement/evenement ~1.0 -> satisfiable by evenement/evenement[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
- alchemy/binary-driver 1.5.0 requires evenement/evenement ~1.0 -> satisfiable by evenement/evenement[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
- Can only install one of: evenement/evenement[1.0.x-dev, v2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: evenement/evenement[v1.0.0, v2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: evenement/evenement[v1.1.0, v2.1.0].
- Installation request for evenement/evenement (locked at v2.1.0) -> satisfiable by evenement/evenement[v2.1.0].
- Installation request for pawlox/video-thumbnail ^1.0 -> satisfiable by pawlox/video-thumbnail[v1.0.3].
- Conclusion: don't install monolog/monolog 2.0.0|install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.5.0|install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.5.1|install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.6.0|install alchemy/binary-driver 1.5.0
- Conclusion: remove monolog/monolog 2.0.0|install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.5.0|install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.5.1|install php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg 0.6.0|install alchemy/binary-driver 1.5.0
- pawlox/video-thumbnail v1.0.3 requires php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg ~0.5 -> satisfiable by php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg[0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.7.x-dev, v0.10.0, v0.11.0, v0.11.1, v0.11.1-pl-1, v0.12, v0.13, v0.14].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.14 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 || ~2.0.0 || ^5.0 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0, 5.0.0, 5.1.0, v2.0.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.13 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 || ~2.0.0 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0, v2.0.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.12 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.11.1-pl-1 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.11.1 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.11.0 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0].
- php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.10.0 requires alchemy/binary-driver ^1.5 -> satisfiable by alchemy/binary-driver[1.5.0, 1.6.0].
- alchemy/binary-driver 5.1.0 requires monolog/monolog ^1.3 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.19.0, 1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.23.0, 1.24.0,
1.25.0, 1.25.1, 1.25.2, 1.25.3, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.x-dev].
- alchemy/binary-driver v2.0.0 requires monolog/monolog ^1.3 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.19.0, 1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.23.0, 1.24.0, 1.25.0,    

1.25.1, 1.25.2, 1.25.3, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.25.3, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.x-dev, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.10.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.11.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.3.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.3.1, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.4.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.4.1, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.5.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.6.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.7.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.8.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.9.0, 2.0.0].
- Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.9.1, 2.0.0].
- Installation request for monolog/monolog (locked at 2.0.0) -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[2.0.0].
```

I am using laravel 6.4.1 
I have researched on the solution but I could not get any.
I don't know that the problem could be.

What could be the solution. thanks

Comment: let me know your composer.json

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur {
    "require": {
        "pawlox/video-thumbnail": "^1.0",
        "lakshmaji/thumbnail": "^1.4",
        "pion/laravel-chunk-upload": "^1.3",
        "pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg": "^5.0"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

1. Add to your composer.json:

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "vcs",
           "url": "https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/BinaryDriver.git"
       }
   ],
   ```
2. Install the `binary-driver` ffmpeg dependency:

   ```
   run composer require php-ffmpeg/binary-driver=dev-master
   ```
3. Install php-ffm:

   ```
   composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffm
   ```

Comment: I am getting this error:  Could not find a matching version of package php-ffmpeg/binary-driver. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev). I am using laravel 6.4.1